# QGIS OGR error creating failure - failed to prepare SQL

Tags: qgis

I'm working in a QGIS v3.4.8 Project with a number of layers including vectors in .tab and .gpkg formats and a raster aerial image. I'm editing .gpkg layers by creating either points or polylines. The creation and saving works fine for quite a while but then I am unable to save the layer/s.

I get a

> WARNING Commit errors

followed by a

> CRITICAL OGR error creating failure : failed to prepare SQL

QGIS is sometimes then not responding.

I'm on a Windows 10 machine. Sometimes I can toggle off the editing and then toggle on and the save will work. On other occasions I have to close down QGIS as it remains unresponsive. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a primary key on your layers ?

Comment: I believe so. When I created the file it automatically added a fid field (Type qlonglong Integer64). When I create a new object and save it the fid field populates automatically with a unique number.

Comment: Sometimes there is a more detailed log about the error, in the messages panel (View menu, Panels, Messages Log). Please, check if there is a more detailed log in OGR tab, or General tab. When you save the layer, some feature is not possible to be saved in the GeoPackage, for some reason. Please, be more specific about the feature that you are creating and trying to save in the GeoPackage, in a way that users with an interest in help you can reproduce your behavior.

Comment: I just tried to create a line feature in my gpkg layer called 
PipesToBeMapped_v2. I was unable to save the feature, QGIS was not responding. Here is the error message from the Messages tab in the Log Messages panel. 2019-12-16T09:55:30     CRITICAL    Layer PipesToBeMapped_v2 : OGR error creating feature -3: failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO "PipesToBeMapped_v2" ( "geom", "Asset_Number", "TempID", "PlanNo", "PlanIDs") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-12-16T09:55:44     WARNING    Commit errors : Could not commit changes to layer PipesToBeMapped_v2